# SQL BETWEEN operator range upper limit for text

Tags: mysql, sql, range, between

In MYSQL, when using between operator for a numerical range, i.e. BETWEEN 1 and 3, it includes 1 and 3 in the output. But when using it for texual range, i.e. BETWEEN 'A' and 'O', it outputs everything starting from A until O. Why does it leave O for texual range?

I tried searching elsewhere. But they only what it does. Nobdoy said why

Comment: Please edit the question, show the table DDL, sample data, and queries

Comment: `BETWEEN 'A' AND 'O'` includes `'O'` but nothing greater than `'O'`. Any text that starts with `'O'` but has at least 1 more char (non blank) is considered greater than `'O'`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above from forpas is correct. The condition `between 'A' and 'O'` does not include strings that are lexically after the single-character string "O". Any word that starts with "O" but is longer than "O" technically sorts after "O", so those are not between 'A' and 'O'.

Demo:

```
mysql> select 'O' between 'A' and 'O' as is_between;
+------------+
| is_between |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'Oz' between 'A' and 'O' as is_between;
+------------+
| is_between |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
```

Here's another test that may explain the issue:

```
mysql> select 'O' = 'Oz', 'O' < 'Oz';
+------------+------------+
| 'O' = 'Oz' | 'O' < 'Oz' |
+------------+------------+
|          0 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

If you want a query that matches strings including any that *start* with "O", you could use one of the following solutions:

```
...where left(mycolumn, 1) between 'A' and 'O'

...where mycolumn regexp '^[A-O]'

...where mycolumn >= 'A' and mycolumn < 'P'
```

The latter is preferred because it can be optimized with an index.

Comment: exactly analogous to `between 1 and 3` not including 3.01